# How to adjust the ingredients when recipe asks for salted peanuts and unsalted butter while I have the opposite?

Tags: baking, substitutions, butter, cookies

The recipe is for cookies. Recipe asks for salted peanuts and unsalted butter while I have the unsalted peanuts and salted butter.

- *Nutralite Table spread:* http://www.nutralite.com/about_nutralite.htm#link2
- *Amul butter:* http://www.amul.com/products/amul-tablebutter-info.php

What should I increase and decrease here to balance out the mixture?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the information from the links you provided and the information found at the [Planter's Nuts website](http://www.planters.com/varieties/nutrition-information.aspx?Site=1&Product=2900001258) (your mileage will vary depending on brand...) and little math (for the peanut's sodium per 100g) we learn that per 100g of each ingredient the sodium content is:

- Nutralite: 786mg/100g
- Amul: 836mg/100g
- Salted Peanuts: 430mg/100g

If the [recipe](http://rasamalaysia.com/peanut-cookies/2/) calls for (using the Amul):

- 4 cups of salted peanuts([@150g/cup](http://www.exclusivelyfood.com.au/2007/04/what-does-1-cup-of-weigh.html) => 600g peanuts => 2500mg sodium)
  and
- 2 tablespoons of butter ([@14g/tablespoon](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/How_much_does_a_tablespoon_of_butter_weigh) => 28g butter => 234mg
  sodium)

So, loosing 2500mg sodium from the peanuts and only recouping 234mg sodium we need to add 2266 mg of sodium...now, [sodium is only about 40% of salt](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/How_many_grams_of_salt_does_a_teaspoon_hold)...meaning that we need 5.6 grams of salt...at [6.375g/teaspoon](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/How_many_grams_of_salt_does_a_teaspoon_hold) means we should add about a teaspoon of salt.

Mathematically, this '*makes sense*', however given that the peanuts are probably to be added at the end I would suggest salting the peanuts directly and then mixing the peanuts(with the salt added) as directed. The process of creaming the butter may distribute the salt a little differently in the mix. I would suggest starting with 3/4 teaspoon of salt then adjusting taste.

Answer (score 0):

to be honest, I use salted butter in all my baking, no matter what the recipe says. I would lightly salt the peanuts, and just use salted butter. i find that generally salted butter is not really salty enough to make that much of a noticeable difference.

Comment: But what about the peanuts?